# How to traverse this json object in Angular js?

Tags: json, angularjs, meanjs

I have this object received from the server:

```
Resource {$promise: Promise, $resolved: false, $get: function, $save: function, $query: function…}
    $promise: Promise
    $resolved: true__v: 
    _id: "54ed85a92908cc9c0cce7044"
    about: "about"
    amenities: Array[0]
        length: 
        __proto__: Array[0]
    created: "2015-02-25T08:19:53.790Z"
    direction: ""
    images: Array[2]
    location: "lkj"
    name: "resort3"
    path: "uploads/projects/ASH_RESORT002"
    profile_pic: "uploads/projects/ASH_RESORT002/images/2013-05-18-1452.jpg"
    resort_id: "ASH_RESORT002"
    room_count: 
    user: Object
    __proto__: Resource
```

I am able to access the $promise and $resolved items in json using obj.$promise and $.resolved respectively. But I am unable to access the non dollar items like "images" by doing obj.images or obj.resort_id

BTW the same items are accesible in the view when used against ng-model. Something like ng-model="obj.resort_id" is successfully binding.

Please guide!

Comment: What do you get if you console.log(obj.resort_id) ?

Answer (score 0):

You aren't including the code that retrieves, or logs, this resource, so I'm taking a bit of a guess here. You may be running into a side-effect of `console.log()`. That function is asynchronous - it doesn't instantly log the "current" values of the object. However, object property access attempts ARE instant. It's possible your object looks 'resolved' when you console.log() it (because it IS, by the time that does its work) but accessing a property directly is looking at an object that is not yet resolved. You can confirm this by `console.log()`'ing the `$resolved` property.

The documentation for $resource contains the appropriate solution:

```
var User = $resource('/user/:userId', {userId:'@id'});
User.get({userId:123}).$promise.then(function(user) {
    // access user.value here.
});
```

That is, you can't access `User.*` immediately after calling `.get()`. You need to "then" the promise and let it resolve.

Comment: BTW the same items are accesible in the view when used against ng-model. Something like ng-model="obj.resort_id" is successfully binding.

Comment: thanks for guiding me. The got the value I want by using timeout function

Comment: Then this is absolutely what is happening to you. The timeout is doing the same as waiting for the promise to resolve. And AngularJS itself is smart enough to draw the correct value when the promise resolves.

Comment: The timeout is imperfect, though. If the AJAX request is very fast, the timeout will slow it down. If it is very slow, the timeout will "miss" it and it will break again. Resolving the promise is the "correct" solution.